# Markov chain probability problem with binomial distribution

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

In a village there are living N people and they decide with an interesting way about some actions. Specifically, if someone proposes an action, then all the N villagers vote for it with YES or NO. The next day each villager re-adjusts her/his opinion independently from the other villagers, and votes again with probability equal to the probability of the total (maximum) supporters of the previous day.This voting process continues until all N villagers agree on the same opinion.

1. Prove that the villagers decide in finite time with probability 1.
2. If the supporters of the proposal action are initially $N_0$, calculate the probability that the village adopts the proposal.

I am given that this is markov chain and if $Y_n$ is the number of supporters of the proposal on day $n$ with transition probabilities (first order):

$Y_n = i$, $Y_{n+1}$ is binomially distributed with parameter $\frac yN$.  This implies $$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1} = j | Y_n = i) = \binom{j}{N} \left(\frac iN\right)^j \left(\frac{N-i}{N}\right)^{N-j}.$$

first of all how he ended that :$$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1} = j | Y_n = i) = \binom{j}{N} \left(\frac iN\right)^j \left(\frac{N-i}{N}\right)^{N-j}$$ What calculations did in order to conclude these transition probabilities?

In addition how can I answer the two sub questions ?

Comment: The first one should not be too hard , just use the fact that it's a finite Markov chain with two absorbing states. The second one, I get the feeling that some martingale technique might be required here. As a Markov chain, the usual first-step analysis will lead to extremely tedious equations.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I would appreciate any help.I am stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part 1, note that at any stage the probability that the villagers all agree in the next round is bounded below by $(1/N)^N$, so the stopping time is bounded above by a geometric random variable with $p=(1/N)^N$, which is of course finite a.s.

The second part, as indicated in the comments, is best approached with martingales. We claim that $Y_n$ is martingale. By the Markov property, the distribution of $Y_{n+1}$ given $Y_n$ is the same as given $Y_n$, $\dots$, $Y_0$  so
$$\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n]=\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\mid Y_n]=Y_n,$$
the last equality since $Y_{n+1}$ given $Y_n=y$ has distribution $\operatorname{Bin}(N, y/N)$. So $Y_n$ is martingale.

Let $T$ be the time that the village reaches a decision. We can verify that $\mathbb ET<\infty$ (from part 1) and the increments of $Y_n$ are bounded by $N$. So we can apply the optional stopping theorem to get that
$$N_0=\mathbb EY_0=\mathbb EY_T=0\cdot\mathbb P(Y_T=0)+N\cdot\mathbb P(Y_T=N).$$

Comment: Right, thank heavens. I wrote it, kept thinking it was wrong and lo and behold, +1.

Comment: About the first part how is bounded by $(1/N)^N$ can you provide me some calculations to better understand it ? So the probability in the second part is $N*\mathbb{P}(Y_T=N)$?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson let's say there are currently 8 people voting YES, then the probability that in the next round everyone votes YES is $(8/N)^N$. So no matter the state, the probability of termination in the next round is certainly at least $(1/N)^N$. This is a pretty crude bound but it is *a* bound so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯